# AngularJS $http GET call getting "Cannot GET /[object%20Object]" error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, api, http, request

I am confused why this is happening. I am fairly new with AngularJS/JS so bear with me. I want to create a simple side project that will assist me in learning how to cook, so I am using a recipe database API caled Yummly that will GET recipes with ingredients and other information.

Here's the documentation: https://developer.yummly.com/documentation.

I tried putting api key and ID in the URL as the API said I can. I also tried putting it in the HTTP headers as the API also said I could. I tried both in postman and both worked, but neither work in my code. I get the error:Cannot GET /[object%20Object]. So I am lost. Perhaps this description from the "How to use GET method" from the documentation is the reason?:

Don’t forget to URL-encode parameter names and values (i.e., [ and ] become %5B and %5D). I don't understand this preceding sentence so...

Here's my code. Thanks so much. Much appreciated!

```
  angular.module("app", [])
.controller('AppController', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
 $scope.greeting = 'Hola!';

$scope.getRecipe = function(){
  $http.get({
    url: 'http://api.yummly.com/v1/api/recipes?q=onion+soup',
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
        'X-Yummly-App-ID':'myID (secret)',
        'X-Yummly-App-Key':'myKey (secret)'
    }
  }).success(function(response) {
      console.log("I got the response.");
    }).error(function(error) {
      console.log("failed", error);
    })
}
}]);
```

Comment: you're already specifying http.get, if you remove the .get part it will work. Otherwise, its just http.get('url',{headers etc...}); please check the docs for http https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Comment: @Ronnie Thank you very much it worked once I removed the .get part! However, I want to learn how to use the shortcut. So I tried $http.get('url', header: {key:key, id:id})  but that didn't work. I then tried config: {header: {key:key, id:id }}, but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `$http.get` is preferred, the code would be:

```
$http.get('http://api.yummly.com/v1/api/recipes', {
  params: {
    q: 'onion+soup'
  }
  headers: {
    'X-Yummly-App-ID':'myID (secret)',
    'X-Yummly-App-Key':'myKey (secret)'
  }
}).success(function(response) {
  console.log("I got the response.");
}).error(function(error) {
  console.log("failed", error);
})
```

According to the official [document](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#get), the syntax of `$http.get` is:

> **get(url, [config]);**
>
> Shortcut method to perform GET request.

The first parameter of `$http.get` is a URL string. If an object is passed (as in the question), it would be converted to string, that's why you get the request sent to `/[object%20Object]` -- `[object%20Object]` is the `toString()` result of the config object.

*Don’t forget to URL-encode parameter names and values (i.e., [ and ] become %5B and %5D). I don't understand this preceding sentence so...*

Don't worry. This will be handled automatically. If the value of `q` above is `'onion+soup[xxx]'`, it would be URL-encoded as `'onion%2Bsoup%5Bxxx%5D'`.

Comment: thanks for the comment. It does not work though (getting same error). I thought $http.get only gets 2 parameters and you gave header as a third. So I tried putting headers into the params object and it still didn't work.

Comment: @TristanSun There are only 2 parameters. The second parameter is an object which has `params` and `headers` field

Comment: ooooh okay I get it now it works. Thank you very much!!